# Kibana - Deleted filter reappears after switching dashboards

Tags: firefox, filter, kibana, elastic-stack

I once created some filters using the `Add a filter +` button in the Kibana Dashboard. I also can delete them, but once I switch to another Dashboard and back again, they reappear. They are also there after rebooting the machine but not after refreshing Kibana in the browser.

I'm using an classic ELK stack and view Kibana via Firefox, all inside my local network.

Answer (score 0):

I feel kinda stupid.
Seems I've been in the edit mode for my dashboard, while adding the filter.
To remove it I had to go to `edit` (in the top), then remove the filter and save the dashboard again.